# Can someone help me on how i can add arm neon support to my code

Tags: c, arm, neon

```
if(length  == 24)
        {
                start = clock();
                for(i = 0 ; i < 24; i++)
                {
                        theta = (abc24[u][i] *M_PI)/4;
                        sample[i].real_sample = cos(theta);
                        sample[i].img_sample = sin(theta);

                        sample_real_vals[i] = reduce_precision(sample[i].real_sample);
                        sample_img_vals[i] = reduce_precision(sample[i].img_sample);
                        printf(" %x  %x\n",sample_real_vals[i], sample_img_vals[i]);
                }
                end = clock();
                cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                printf("time used = %f \n",cpu_time_used);
}
```

here, abc24[i][j] is an array of size 30 x 24.
The clock at the end is just for finding the execution time of the program
Is it possible to use neon intrinsics in the sin and cos part?If so could someone help me with it?

Comment: You definitely want to remove the `printf` from the loop body when you want to vectorize it or messure the execution time.

Comment: If you want an answer, ask the right question in proper form especially for optimization purpose. What's the data type of abc????? `float`,  `double` ore even `int`?  Where is `u`? Where is the function `reduce_precision`????

Comment: actually i dont need to make any changes in the reduce precision function

Comment: i only need to have theta vectorized so i can increase the speed of finding sine and cos using arm_neon

Comment: You CAN vectorize `theta`, but you CANNOT do it with `cos` and `sin`, unless you can afford to make compromises in precision. Which means you need to transfer `theta` from vector registers to `VFP` registers that comes with a steep penalty in addition to the actual transfer costs. Whatever gain you made by vectorizing `theta` might become void or even worse.

Comment: How many bits are there in `sample_real_vals[i]` and what is the range of `abc24[u][i]`? If the constraints are strict enough, this should be easily doable in fixed point arithmetic and with neon intrinsics (also assuming, that `sample[i].real_sample` and the imaginary part could be thrown away...).

Answer (score 0):

There aren't cos or sin Neon functions, so for fast speed you'd want to use a polynomial approximation. How approximate will depend on speed-wanted vs acceptable accuracy loss, but potentially could be faster even before the vectorization that becomes possible.

Vectorization of the polynomial will depend on polynomial implemented, but data layout will be important. Don't transfer back and forth between Neon and normal registers more than you need to, there is a cost.

For more help, there are intrinsics and assembler guides (& instrinsics search engine) at https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon which are very helpful